# AddressAccessDeniedException : resolve it without netsh?

Tags: c#, wcf, http, user-permissions

I encountered the exception `AddressAccessDeniedException` because my processus does not have the right to register the URL. I first ran my program as an administrator : ok, it worked.

But I now want to distribute my application, and I would like every user to be able to run it without having to be administrator.

Is there a way to automatically grant the access to the user?

I saw the command :

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8000/ user=DOMAIN\UserName
```

Should I use that? If yes, how?

What I would like to do would be to grant the access withouth being an administrator... said like that, it seems stupid, but may be...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not possible. Windows uses kernel driver to process HTTP requests and opening listeners on this driver is secured by ACLs (access control list). If you want to open listener so that your application can listen on requests from other machines you must either run it as administrator to pass ACL or you must have permissions (= you must be in ACL). You can also turn off UAC (user access control) to bypass these checks.

`netsh` is a tool allowing you to set up ACL for HTTP.sys (kernel driver). You can give permissions to any user to listen on selected port but obviously you must be admin to give these permissions or you must have permissions to delegate rights for already configured permissions otherwise the whole point of this security will be gone.

Add that `netsh` call to your installation package and require the installation to be done as admin (that is quite common for many applications). Also be aware that netsh works only on Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2. For Windows 2003 and Windows XP (at least SP2 is required) you need another tool called `httpcfg` which is not part of OS installation (it must be installed separately).

Comment: Ow... So, I'm just trying to do something impossible? Btw thansk for the explanation, it seems I'll have to use netsh! Thanks ;)

Comment: Users might want to change ports of my Windows Service which runs as a service account.  Service accounts shouldn't be admins, right?  Is there a way to give the service account the full permissions to HTTP.sys - a subset of the full Administrators permissions.  All I can see is that netsh allows reservation of certain ports.  Requiring command-line commands after changing the port or having a separate executable or batch seems unnecessarily complicated.