# When self-hosting what exactly causes AddressAccessDeniedException : HTTP could not register URL

Tags: windows, acl, firewall, owin, self-hosting

I am writing a bdd test for a component that will startup phantomjs and hit a specific route on my site and do processing on that. Because the component is fundamentally about automating a phantom instance there is no way to easily stub out the http requests.

So I want to stub out a self-hosted endpoint that will stub out the data I'm after. Because this is a unit test I think its really important for it to run in isolation so I do something like this:

```
   async Task can_render_html_for_slide_async() {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:54331");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Controller", "{controller}", new {});
        using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config)) {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var resp = await client.GetStringAsync(config.BaseAddress+"/Stub");
            Console.WriteLine(resp);
        }
    }

public class StubController : ApiController
{
    public string Get() {
        return "Booyah";
    }
}
```

Which gets me

```
AddressAccessDeniedException : HTTP could not register URL http://+:54331/
```

[I understand that netsh or Admin mode is required for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7672861/5056) but I don't understand why. Nodejs for example runs perfectly fine on windows but has no such requirement.

Also [using OWIN directly](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana) needs no netsh-ing. So....what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an article about [it on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager), it was done to make it possible for multiple application to share the same port.
You can have both, IIS and Apache (or OWIN in your case) listenening port 80. The routing to the right application is done thanks to the path of the url.
IIS and Apache both would use this driver (http.sys). But you need permission to "reserve" a path.
Administrators are always authorized. For other users, use netsh or my GUI tool [HttpSysManager](http://httpsysmanager.codeplex.com/) to set ACL.

Comment: So I'm not sure what you are saying in this case. Is `HttpSelfHostServer` using http.sys?

Comment: Yes. In fact I don't think there is any class in .NET to host an http server using normal socket instead of http sys.

Comment: As I point out in the question, using OWIN directly through `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp` works fine

Comment: by the way there's some broken html in your article when you post the smile image

Comment: WebApp, by default use OwinHttpListener which use .NET HttpListener which use http.sys. You can confirm it by running netstat -a -b it should tell you that it can't get the process that have the port on which you are listening to. Because what is listening on the port is http.sys. It works fine with WebApp because you are running it as an administrator, so you don't have to set the ACL.
You can_render_html_for_slide_async is not running as admin. (See which account with System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name and set the Url ACL with netsh or my tool.

Comment: I do not run visual studio as an administrator. In fact these are two tests in the same class in the same project, one works the other doesn't.

Comment: explanation : Owin use a port or path on which the authorization is already set.
Take a look with netsh to see which port/path it listens to and use the same for your unit test.
This is exactly as I told you, so you will see. (netsh http show servicestate if you want to know which path is currently listened)

Comment: I really appreciate you continuing to answer, I'm just still not sure that I get it. Both the OWIN and non-owin self-host versions are in the same project, using the same port (There is no conflict because this is a spike and I only run one test at a time). Would it help if I created a test class to share or do you know what I am saying?

Comment: the only explanation I see is that the non owin project does not use http.sys, which I highly doubt.
Use netstat -a -b to see if the process is directly listening on the port with the non owin test

Answer (score 1):

Any method that requires giving permission via netsh uses a Windows kernel driver to provide http access.

If a library opens a socket itself and handles the http communication that way, no netsh use is needed.

So to answer your question, some methods are using the kernel driver and some are handling the protocol themselves.

Comment: I see, isn't windows.api using all the same owin stuff though?